# Python- Create a url Regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I want to create url which accepts both `installation_name` and `action_type`. I'm able to create for `installation_id`, but not for `action_type`. how can I do that?

Following is for only `installation_name`

```
url(r'(?P<installation_name>[0-9]+)/', views.ApiActions.as_view()),
```

Comment: Could you show an example of the URL you want to handle?

Comment: @arocks - its like `locahost:8000/actions?installation_name="abc"&action_type="xyz"`

Answer (score 0):

The `installation_name` and `action_type` in your URL are query parameters, not part of the URL tree.  The way django will resolve it is to find a view for a URL which matches `/actions`, and pass the rest of the URL string as request parameters, Your view can use it something like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    installation_name = request.GET.get('installation_name')
    action_type = request.GET.get('action_type')
```

If you want to use a different URL route you need to construct the URL differently, e.g.:

```
r'/actions/(?P<installation_name>[0-9]+)/(?P<action_type>.+)'
```

Using the values in your example (although note that `installation_name=abc` does not match your regex):

```
/actions/abc/xyz
```

Comment: Thanks @aquavitae. If you are aware of building RESTful API, can yu please share your views on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452949/django-swagger-how-do-i-add-different-parameter-values-apart-from-models-varia